# Adjacency matrix from Euclidean distance matrix given in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I wanted to know how to create adjacency matrix from euclidean distance matrix i've created before.
for example :

```
 Edm =  [0       7.7466  7.7534  0       3.7296  2.8171;
         7.7466  0       0.0068  7.7466  4.0170  4.9295;
         7.7534  0.0068  0       7.7534  4.0239  4.9364;
         0       7.7466  7.7534  0       3.7296  2.8171;
         3.7296  4.0170  4.0239  3.7296  0       0.9125;
         2.8171  4.9295  4.9364  2.8171  0.9125  0     ]
```

`Edm` shows conectivity node 1-6 based on their euclidean distance between each other. Diagonal must be 0 because distance from the same node is zero.

is there a way for me to retrieve an adjaceny matrix with 2 nearest neighbor from `Edm` above?

Comment: You have a special case for node 6 - node 1 and 4 have the same distance and both could be the second nearest neighbors. How should this case be treated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get Mohsen's answer to work, so here's my (more cumbersome) suggestion:

```
sz = size(Edm,1);
n = 2;             % Number of desired smallest distances
E = Edm + diag(Inf(1,sz));
[~, mm] = sort(E);

mmi = mm(1:n,:)';  % n smallest distances (in your example, n = 2)

Edm_idx = sparse(mmi(:),repmat(1:sz,1,n),1,sz,sz);

Adj = full(Edm.*Edm_idx);
```

Not that there are non-diagonal values in `Edm` that are `0`. If these are suppose to be `Inf`, (as in not connected), you must account for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the diagonal to `Inf` and use `bsxfun` to compare the elements in each column with the minimum value in that column:

```
E = Edm + diag(Inf(1,size(Edm,1)));
A = bsxfun(@eq, E, min(E));
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? It turns out wrong when I test it. (I don't get a symmetric adjacency matrix)

Comment: @RobertP. I do get a symmetric one. What element is different between `A` and `A'`?

Comment: It looks to me that it just finds the smallest value (except for zero) in each column. I get `sum(A) = [1 1 1 .. ]`, how about you?

Comment: It is expected. That is because in the example there is no point that has more than one closest neighbour.